# How do the Uniswap Router contract functions ending in "SupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" work?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

The Uniswap router contract has a few methods ending in `*SupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`, e.g. `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`.

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol

I vaguely (think I) understand that these methods are supposed to be called for swapping tokens that somehow take a tax/rake during transfers.

I have a few questions regarding these:

1. In a nutshell, what is the difference in behavior for these functions different from the regular swap functions?  Do they somehow interact with the minOut parameters?
2. How does the Dex UI know which method to call?  How does it know the `SupportingFee` version needs to be called instead of the standard swap?
3. What happens if my web3 script calls the wrong version of the method? Failures? Wrong amounts out?

Comment: Nope. Never figured it out.  I try the normal method first now and if that fails, I use the second one.

Comment: @user1142433 Why you dont call the  ```SupportingFee``` method for all tokens? it will fail?